# How to process large XML file (9 GB) with STAX api

Tags: java, xml, io, stream, stax

I'm always getting Heap memory problem while processing huge file.Here i'm processing 9 GB xml file.

This is my code.

```
            XMLInputFactory inputFactory = XMLInputFactory.newInstance();
            InputStream in = new FileInputStream(sourcePath);
            XMLEventReader eventReader =  inputFactory.createXMLEventReader(in);

            Map<String, Cmt> mapCmt = new ConcurrentHashMap<String, Cmt>();
            while (eventReader.hasNext()) {
                XMLEvent event = eventReader.nextEvent();
                if (event.isStartElement()) {
                //some processing and assigning value to map
                Cmt cmt = new Cmt();
                //get attributes
                cmt.setDetails(attribute.getValue());
                mapCmt.put(someKey,cmt);
                }
            }
```

I'getting heap memory problem in iteration after some time.
Please help me to write optimized code.

Note: server have available 3 GB heap space. I can't increase server space.
I'm executing with following parameters - -Xms1024m -Xmx3g

My xml looks like this.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<DatosAbonados xmlns="http://www.cnmc.es/DatosAbonados">
    <DatosAbonado Operacion="1" FechaExtraccion="2015-10-08">
        <Titular>
            <PersonaJuridica DocIdentificacionJuridica="A84619488" RazonSocial="HERMANOS ROJAS" NombreComercial="PINTURAS ROJAS"/>
        </Titular>
        <Domicilio Escalera=" " Piso=" " Puerta=" " TipoVia="AVENIDA" NombreVia="MANOTERAS" NumeroCalle="10" Portal=" " CodigoPostal="28050" Poblacion="Madrid" Provincia="28"/>
        <NumeracionAbonado>
            <Rangos NumeroDesde="211188600" NumeroHasta="211188699" ConsentimientoGuias-Consulta="1" VentaDirecta-Publicidad="1" ModoPago="1">
                <Operador RazonSocial="11888 SERVICIO CONSULTA TELEFONICA S.A." DocIdentificacionJuridica="A83519389"/>
            </Rangos>
        </NumeracionAbonado>
    </DatosAbonado>
    <DatosAbonado Operacion="1" FechaExtraccion="2015-10-08">
        <Titular>
            <PersonaJuridica DocIdentificacionJuridica="A84619489" RazonSocial="HERMANOS RUBIO" NombreComercial="RUBIO PELUQUERIAS"/>
        </Titular>
        <Domicilio Escalera=" " Piso=" " Puerta=" " TipoVia="AVENIDA" NombreVia="BURGOS" NumeroCalle="18" Portal=" " CodigoPostal="28036" Poblacion="Madrid" Provincia="28"/>
        <NumeracionAbonado>
            <Rangos NumeroDesde="211186000" NumeroHasta="211186099" ConsentimientoGuias-Consulta="1" VentaDirecta-Publicidad="1" ModoPago="1">
                <Operador RazonSocial="11888 SERVICIO CONSULTA TELEFONICA S.A." DocIdentificacionJuridica="A83519389"/>
            </Rangos>
        </NumeracionAbonado>
    </DatosAbonado>
</DatosAbonados>
```

My Cmt class is :

```
public class Cmt {
    private List<DetailInfo> details;

    public List<DetailInfo> getDetails() {
        return details;
    }
    public void setDetails(DetailInfo detail) {
        if(details == null){
            details = new ArrayList<DetailInfo>();
        }
        this.details.add(detail);
    }
}
```

> Actually Cmt object is very less, But i have DetailInfo object for
>   every  element. So  huge no. of DetailInfo object is
>   created.

My Logic is this :

```
if (startElement.getName().getLocalPart().equals("DatosAbonado")) {
                    detailInfo = new DetailInfo();

                    Iterator<Attribute> attributes = startElement.getAttributes();
                    while (attributes.hasNext()) {
                        Attribute attribute = attributes.next();
                         if(attribute.getName().toString().equals("Operacion")){
                            detailInfo.setOperacion(attribute.getValue());
                        }
                    }
                }
if (event.isEndElement()) {
                EndElement endElement = event.asEndElement();
                if (endElement.getName().getLocalPart().equals("DatosAbonado")) {
                    Cmt cmt = null;
                    if(mapCmt.keySet().contains(identificador)){
                        cmt = mapCmt.get(identificador);
                    } else{
                        cmt = new Cmt();
                    }
                    cmt.setDetails(detailInfo);
                    mapCmt.put(identificador, cmt);
}
}
```

Comment: how many `Cmt` objects do you create in this process? Probably too much to fit into your available memory....

Comment: You aren't showing all: where does `attribute` come from? How many Cmt objects are you storing in mapCmt and how big are they? Also, creating a Cmt for each start-element event seems rather strange.

Comment: @laune Here i've written kind of pseudo code. very less Cmt object is created but Cmt object contains a list of another object which is created for every <DatosAbonado>.

Comment: @wero Here i've written kind of pseudo code. very less Cmt object is created but Cmt object contains a list of another object which is created for every <DatosAbonado>.

Comment: If you would post exact details about DatosAbonado and what you store from that in the stored List elements one might be able to advise. The XML appears to be extremely redundant, i.e., the two `<DatosAbonado>` have much in common. This will result in a huge waste of memory. Even String.intern might reduce memory.

Comment: @laune please find the exact logic with DatosAbonado . And each DatosAbonado  is different.it seems same here because its a sample xml.

Comment: I hope that there are parts you haven't shown under "My Logic is this", because that's storing a String value in an object which is in another object that goes into mapCmt.

Comment: Streaming XSLT (with 3.0) might be another way for reducing the big XML to a dataset that can be handled without causing OOM.

Answer (score 2):

The root of your problems is most likely this:

```
mapCmt.put(someKey, cmt);
```

You are populating a hashmap with a number of large `Cmt` objects.  You need to do one of the following:

- Process the data immediately rather than saving it in a data structure.
- Write the data out to a database for later querying.
- Increase the heap size.
- Figure out a less "memory hungry" representation for your data.

The last two approaches don't scale though.  As you increase the size of the input file, you will need progressively more memory ... until you eventually exceed the memory capacity of your execution platform.

Comment: Very less Cmt object is created ,but Cmt object contains a list of another object which is created for every <DatosAbonado>.Please check the updated question.

Comment: That doesn't materially change my diagnosis, or the possible solutions.

Comment: my next approach is your 2nd point only as i think im left with no other option.Thanks for your valuable suggestion.

Comment: @Bunty If you're interested, do a quick research into "ETL" and "data warehousing". This is basically step one of the combination of the two; extracting the data from the source and "staging" it into a storage format (a database) which makes the data structured and accessible and where it can be easily validated, transformed and then loaded into its final destination. Its a strategy that makes data processing robust and manageable. Well worth the resources, IMO.

Answer (score 0):

DatosAbonnado is the killer indeed. If you have plenty of 'm this will cause your application to choke.

The approach is simply not scalable. As pointed out by Stephan C you need to process the DatosAbonnado as it arrives and not collect them in a container.

Since this is a typical scenario for which I developed LDX+ code generator, I went to the steps of:

- creating an XML Schema file from XML (because you had not provided it) using: https://devutilsonline.com/xsd-xml/generate-xsd-from-xml
- generate code with LDX+

This code generator is actually using SAX, and the resulting code allows you to:

- serialize the complexElements to Java objects
- configure how to treat 1 to many relationships (like the one you have here) at runtime

I uploaded the code here: https://bitbucket.org/lolkedijkstra/ldx-samples
To see the code navigate to the Source folder. There you'll find DatosAbonnados.

This approach really scales well (memory consumption is flat)